# How to add IN statement with JOIN ON clause in tablegateway ZF2

Tags: database, join, zend-framework2, in-clause

Getting all result so far until I added a 'IN' statement with join ON clause

My code is something like this:

```
// $this->table = 'category';
$sql = $this->getSql();
$select = $sql->select();
$select->join('user_category_subscriptions', 'user_category_subscriptions.category_id = category.id AND user_category_subscriptions.status IN (1,2,3,4)', array(), 'left');
$select->where(array('category.user_id = 2 OR (user_category_subscriptions.status IN (2,4))'));
```

Error

```
ZEND\DB\ADAPTER\EXCEPTION\INVALIDQUERYEXCEPTION
File:E:\htdocs\myproj\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php:245
Message:Statement could not be executed
```

Used 'echo $select->getSqlString();' to print the query:

```
SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
LEFT JOIN "user_category_subscriptions" 
ON "user_category_subscriptions"."category_id" = "categories"."category_id" AND "user_category_subscriptions"."status" IN ("1""," "2""," "3""," "4")
WHERE category.user_id = 2 OR (user_category_subscriptions.status IN (2,4))
```

So the problem is zend's auto converting **(1,2,3,4)** into **("1""," "2""," "3""," "4")**

Any idea to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can pass an expression instead of the join string:

```
// $this->table = 'category';
$sql = $this->getSql();
$select = $sql->select();

$join = new Expression('user_category_subscriptions.category_id = category.id AND user_category_subscriptions.status IN (1,2,3,4)');

$select->join('user_category_subscriptions', $join, array(), 'left');
$select->where(array('category.user_id = 2 OR (user_category_subscriptions.status IN (2,4))'));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$select->where
       ->AND->NEST->equalTo('category.user_id', 2)
       ->addPredicate(new Sql\Predicate\In('user_category_subscriptions.status', array(2,4)));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Please see the 'IN' statement with JOIN ON clause (i.e. like... ON foo.id=bar.fooid AND foo.barid IN (1,2,3)). Only the 'IN' statement with ON creating all trouble, not the IN statement which is attached with WHERE.